# knockout multiple filter options

Tags: arrays, knockout.js, filter, filtering

I am stuck with knockout on array filters / how to filter an array with multiple options.

What I am attempting to do is find the correct item from 'matrix' where `type == "nono"` and `data -> beds == 1.`

I can easily filter by type == "nono" but I am stuck on how to get items within data.

I hope the fiddle shows what I am attempting to do, but if you need any clarification then let me know.

e.g. I want it to return 
     {
             id: 1,
             beds: 1,
             baths: 1,
             priceLow: 1564,
             priceHigh: 1930
     }

[Link to JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8dpQ/195/)

Comment: Something like this maybe. http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/R8dpQ/196/

Comment: perfect - it was running the foreach I wasn't getting!! Stick it as answer so I can accept!! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `forEach` your nested `data` object and build an array if `data.beds==1`.

Example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/R8dpQ/196/